# Iframe | Mobile back button on youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have got a video that appears in a light box from you tube, a custom one not a plugin.

On mobile when displayed portrait the video spans the full page width which looks nice and leaves some room at the top and bottom to click out.

The issue is when I go landscape the video fills the full screen and you cannot get back onto the page. My initial reaction was to hit the phones back button but I don't know a way of getting this to simply remove my lightbox. Is there a way in JS of getting a `onclick` off the phones back button?

The reason it goes full screen is because I am keeping the aspect ratio

```
        var width: number = $('.youtube-video-lightbox').outerWidth();
        var height: number = (width / 16) * 9;
        $('.youtube-video-lightbox').height(height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following code:

You need to listen to navigation event and state.direction.

```
 $(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    // close the light box here
  }
  if (direction == 'forward') {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

More details in [this link](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-control-back-and-forward-button-in-jquery-mobile/)

Tested the above code in my mobile and it works fine. You might need to stop the program flow after closing the light box so that default navigation of the back button is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Weave: http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#e110ed7e89c3a38335739656a02f9850

Have you thought of trying a [Pure CSS Based Lightbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBWiU_6HLDI)?

```js
$('[data-target]').on('click', function() {
  $('.page').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-target'));
});

$('#call').on('change', function() {
  (this.checked) ? "" : $('.page').attr('src', '');
});
```

```css
input[id=call] {
  display: none;
}

a {
  margin: 1em;
}

.bg,
.content {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: all ease-in 150ms;
}

.bg {
  background: #515151;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.58);
}

.content {
  margin: 2.6352em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #fff;
}

input[id=call]:checked ~ .bg,
input[id=call]:checked ~ .content {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="call" type="checkbox" />
<p>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="http://bing.com/" class="pointer block">
    <label for="call" class="pointer">Bing</label>
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="http://duckduckgo.com/" class="pointer block">
    <label for="call" class="pointer">DuckDuckGo</label>
  </a>
</p>
<label for="call" class="bg pointer"></label>
<div class="content">
  <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" class="page"></iframe>
</div>
```